# Bad sound quality and headphones not working

Tags: 10.10, sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Poor sound quality and headphones not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10465/poor-sound-quality-and-headphones-not-working)

Using Ubuntu 10.10 on a HP Pavilion t3019.es, which has a Realtek ALC880 soundcard. It has 6 rear jack outputs, plus digital audio input and output, plus 3 front jacks (mic, headphones and a blue one which i don't know what's for).

The sound on my computer is very low, and when i raise the volume up to 50%, it starts sounding distorted, crackling. Also, the headphones don't work when i plug them (it just keeps on playing through the speakers).

I tried to comment the "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf" file according to the soundcard and jacks in my computer, but none of the lines added worked (naturally, didn't added them at once). I found out that adding "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" to it made the sound better, but it's not as good as in Windows yet.

I've fulfilled a bug report with the **ubuntu-bug audio** command, and sent it to launchpad. Here it is: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/709799

Any ideas? Other than setting the PCM value, please, didn't work for me.

Thanks.