# Is there any way to use the audio input of a 13" MacBook Pro?

Tags: sound, macbook, input

First question here!

I have a 13" MacBook Pro with Ubuntu 10.10 and I get every piece of hardware working without problem... but sound input.

My machine can reproduce sound correctly, but I can record nothing. The 13" MacBook pro only has one jack connector for both, input and output.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer at [Bad sound quality and headphones not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22297/bad-sound-quality-and-headphones-not-working/23883#23883) for the steps to troubleshoot the issue and provide more information. This is an issue with sound support in the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You either need hardware that works with that combo-port or you need an adapter that splits it into one line-in and one line-out port. Bottom line: not an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: That's not the point. I only want to send audio and recording, not both send audio and listen through the same jack connector. I can listen what I'm recording through the laptop speakers.

Comment: You cannot use a combo port with an ordinary line-in jack, only line-out works fine with those ports. An example for such an adapter (note the three rings on the jack) is the [SteelSeries Mobile Device Adapter](http://shop.steelseries.com/index.php/steelseries-mobile-device-adapter.html) (I guess you'll find cheaper ones on eBay).

Comment: Is not there a way to do it through software? On Mac OS X I could switch between use the connector for input or output...

Comment: Oh, really? I didn't know that it's possible in Mac OS X, sorry. I just haven't found a way to make this work in Ubuntu and Windows 7, so I have assumed that it's a hardware limitation.

Comment: No probs. Same here, that's why I asked here. Maybe someone has the solution... :-/